# Unable to bypass spring security filter chain for specific endpoints with the permitAll() and web.ignoring() methods

Tags: spring-security

I'm using Spring Security for Single Sign On implementation. I've added the Spring Security filter chain in my application with annotations, and not in the `web.xml`.

I want the Spring Security filter chain to only apply to the `/saml` URLs, and I don't want the `/myapi` requests to go through Spring Security. But my `/myapi` requests are still going through the Spring Security filter chain, and Spring's filters.

Here's my code for Spring Security filter registration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .addFilterBefore(new SamlExtensionUrlForwardingFilter(), DisableEncodeUrlFilter.class)
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .antMatchers("/saml/*").authenticated()
                        .antMatchers("/myapi/*").permitAll()
                )
            .saml2Login()
                    .successHandler(new MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/myapi/*");
    }
```

With the `webSecurityCustomizer()`, I tried to exclude the `/myapi/` endpoints from the Spring Security workflow, and bypass the Spring Security filter chain and other Spring Security filters for the endpoint.

Additionally, I tried to get the same results with the following as well, assuming that `permitAll()` would mean Spring Security authorization is not required for the `/myapi` requests:

```java
.antMatchers("/myapi/*").permitAll()
```

Neither of the above two worked, and the `/myapi` requests still go through Spring'a filters like `DisableEncodeUrlFilter`, `CsrfFilter` etc. Ideally, I want only `/saml/*` requests to go through the Spring Security filter chain and Spring related filters.

Comment: Your first solution with `WebSecurityCustomizer` should work. Your second solution with `.antMatchers("/myapi/*").permitAll()` cannot work, because you doesn't restrict the filter chain, you only configure the authorisation.

Comment: What exact URL do you call? Your `WebSecurityCustomizer` only matches `/myapi/*`, so for example `/myapi/x/y` is not machted.

Comment: I was able to finally ignore the `/myapi/` endpoints with :-`web.ignoring().antMatchers("/myapi/**")`

 @dur Is that what you were suggesting in the above comment?

Comment: Yes, that was it.